# Ускорение поиска в PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, поиск, like

При поиске по текстовому полю с использованием **LIKE '%text%'** становятся очень ощутимы временные затраты по сравнению с **LIKE 'text%'**, видимо не может использоваться индексация. Каким образом это правильно обойти?
**SIMILAR TO**, **substring** работают ещё медленнее.

Видимо нужно смотреть в сторону **GIN**

Answer (score 3):

Рекомендую посмотреть на модуль pg_trgm, идущий в стандартной поставке
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/pgtrgm.html

Вот кусочек из документации:

Beginning in PostgreSQL 9.1, these index types also support index searches for LIKE and ILIKE, for example

SELECT * FROM test_trgm WHERE t LIKE '%foo%bar';

The index search works by extracting trigrams from the search string and then looking these up in the index. The more trigrams in the search string, the more effective the index search is. Unlike B-tree based searches, the search string need not be left-anchored.

Beginning in PostgreSQL 9.3, these index types also support index searches for regular-expression matches (~ and ~* operators), for example

SELECT * FROM test_trgm WHERE t ~ '(foo|bar)';

The index search works by extracting trigrams from the regular expression and then looking these up in the index. The more trigrams that can be extracted from the regular expression, the more effective the index search is. Unlike B-tree based searches, the search string need not be left-anchored.

For both LIKE and regular-expression searches, keep in mind that a pattern with no extractable trigrams will degenerate to a full-index scan.

The choice between GiST and GIN indexing depends on the relative performance characteristics of GiST and GIN, which are discussed elsewhere. As a rule of thumb, a GIN index is faster to search than a GiST index, but slower to build or update; so GIN is better suited for static data and GiST for often-updated data.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен модуль tsearch2 -- встроенный в PostgreSQL начиная с версии 8.3 полнотекстовый поиск. Легко гуглится даже информация на русском языке, например, http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/postgres/talks/fts_pgsql_intro.html.